# How can I take this two divs one centre and other top right?

Tags: html, css

How can I take this two divs one centre and other top right? I can manage to to take them but the second div which is "top" comes under right the first div which is "kng". What am I doing wrong? Explanation would be welcomed..thanks

```css
#smedia {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#smedia a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-color: black;
}

#header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#fb {
  height: 23px;
}

.top {
  float: right;
}

#kng {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#kng img {
  height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

```html
<div id="kng">
  <img src="img/kng.jpg">
</div>
<div class="top">
  <div id="header">
    <a href="#"> Sign in</a> |
    <a href="signup.php"> Sign up </a> |
    <a href="#"> Help </a>
  </div>
  <div id="smedia">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://www.ransomesjacobsen.com/themes/jacobsen/images/icons/facebook-icon-small.png" alt="facebook" id="fb"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com"> <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/_img/icon-top-twitter.png" alt="twitter" id="tw"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com"> <img src="http://dunedin.art.museum/templates/dpag/images/instagram-icon.png" alt="instagram" id="ins"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have so many errors in the code?

Comment: can you say how?

Comment: Dude, don't be rude and first understand what happened: **1.** I corrected your question and formatted to be nice. **2.** I answered with the solution as well to make it work. Seriously, not even thanking but you are asking! `:(`

Comment: lol..whose being rude? theres only two simple errors according to w3 validator

Comment: There's a button called Refresh. And there's something called notification, which would have told that you got an answer. Kindly check below! `:(`

Comment: Boss, those are **not simple errors**!

Comment: Sure thanks @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you need to use the `float` in this way:

```css
#smedia {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#smedia a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-color: black;
}

#header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#fb {
  height: 23px;
}

.top {
  float: right;
}

#kng {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#kng img {
  height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div id="header">
    <a href="#"> Sign in</a> |
    <a href="signup.php"> Sign up </a> |
    <a href="#"> Help </a>
  </div>
  <div id="smedia">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://www.ransomesjacobsen.com/themes/jacobsen/images/icons/facebook-icon-small.png" alt="facebook" id="fb"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com"> <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/_img/icon-top-twitter.png" alt="twitter" id="tw"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com"> <img src="http://dunedin.art.museum/templates/dpag/images/instagram-icon.png" alt="instagram" id="ins"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="kng">
  <img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Logo">
</div>
```

Swap the right floated element to come as the first and there you go! And `display: block` instead of `display: table`!

If you want the image to be purely centred, you can do this:

```css
#smedia {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#smedia a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-color: black;
}

#header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#fb {
  height: 23px;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#kng {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#kng img {
  height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div id="header">
    <a href="#"> Sign in</a> |
    <a href="signup.php"> Sign up </a> |
    <a href="#"> Help </a>
  </div>
  <div id="smedia">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://www.ransomesjacobsen.com/themes/jacobsen/images/icons/facebook-icon-small.png" alt="facebook" id="fb"> </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com"> <img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/_img/icon-top-twitter.png" alt="twitter" id="tw"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com"> <img src="http://dunedin.art.museum/templates/dpag/images/instagram-icon.png" alt="instagram" id="ins"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="search">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="kng">
  <img src="//placehold.it/150?text=Logo">
</div>
```